# How to change the background color of cardview and save that changes?

Tags: java, android

I tried to change the background color of cardview once it opened by using  **`cardView setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)`** . But i don't know how to save that changes.  Please help me.

Comment: "once it opened" - please elaborate if you changed it while opening app or you're changing it at runtime.

Comment: Is changing the color while clicking the cardview at that time only. But when I open the app again,  there is no any changes.  I don't know how to save that changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shared Preference to store your color and set the color which is stored in shared Preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     editor.putInt("color", "yourColor");
     editor.apply();
```